# VB #const, /const, etc

Tags: vb.net, conditional-statements

We have base code we use in many projects that has two major "parts", XL and DP. You might make a new project that uses DP without XL, or XL without DP. But when you use both together, you want them to know about each other, which we use a series of conditionals for...

```
#if AmUsingDP then
... additional amazing functionality here ...
#end if
```

Normally these conditionals are set using the Advanced Compile Options. But this means every time we make a new project you have to dig through the settings, which is a major PITA.

In C, one simply does a #define in one of the files, and then simply importing that file into your project is all you need to do.

I thought that maybe #const would handle this, but that is local to the file, which is the opposite of what I want. I saw the documentation on /define, but is that something that even works *inside* a file? Is there anything similar to C's #define we can use?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can manage configurations, i.e., you can add new configurations besides `Debug` and `Release` and define different custom compilation constants for each one of them. You could have configurations called `Debug XL, Debug DP, Debug XL+DP, Release XL, Release DP, Release XL+DP` this way you don't forget to set the constants.

You can also define different command line arguments in the configurations. This was useful in one of my projects, where the application could be started in different modes through command line arguments.

---

If you are using the same configurations in different projects, consider creating [project templates.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)

Comment: This solution simply moves the thing I will forget from one dialog box to another. Now instead of having to remember to set Advanced Compile Options, I have to remember to set up a different build configuration, which I suspect is even more work. Is there really no way to do this IN THE FILES?

Comment: I realize in retrospect I used questionable description which has led to this confusion. I have edited the original question.

Comment: The advantage of having different configurations is that you see the active setting in front of you, instead of having it in a hidden place.